# Can't get Grooveshark WebApp to work

Tags: webapps, grooveshark

I just upgrade to 12.10 and I was thrill to use WebApps, specially Grooveshark's. So I went to the website, click "Integrate" and... nothing.

No icon on my dash, no controls on my sound notification panel.

Did I do something wrong ? How can I get it working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it started working once I switched back to the old layout on grooveshark. Which would make sense that the webapp was designed for the old layout instead of the relatively new one.

Answer (score 0):

They are not working, it's a bog look here: [report at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webapps-applications/+bug/1068662)

Comment: My GMail and YouTube WebAppas are working

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that the software or plug-in is using a domain that no longer exist, so, I changed the main domain in the config files of the a app (unity-webapps-grooveshark) and that's it.

The files are:

```
/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-groovesharkr/grooveshark.user.js
/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-grooveshark/manifest.json
```

Just changed

```
http://grooshark.com
```

for

```
http://grooveshark.im
```

And

```
grooveshark.com
```

for

```
grooveshark.im
```