# How to re-enable Unity WebApps in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, chromium, webapps

Back in previous versions of Ubuntu I've removed Unity WebApps packages. Now I want to reinstall them.

I use Chromium, installed `unity-chromium-extension` package. Also reset default **dconf** settings (see screenshot below).

I'm currently trying to install Grooveshark webapp, as you see already included grooveshark.com domain in the **dconf** settings, also installed `unity-webapps-grooveshark` package, but still cant make WebApps work in Ubuntu.

Besides when I go to Chromium settings there is no **Desktop Integration** properties at all, though 'Unity WebApps Chromium extension" is enabled.

Any thoughts?

[image]

**UPDATE (Also See UPDATE 2 below)**: After some package reinstallations I got this message when I visited twitter.com with Chromium:

[image]

When I accepted and opened Twitter app from the Dash it was opened as a standalone Chromium app, but there still were no additional Launcher options when I right-clicked the icon. I think it still hasn't integrated properly.

**Update 2**: I just tried to install Reddit app, accepted the confirmation box in Chromium but Reddit app has not appeared in the Dash. Seems above mentioned Twitter app was a remaining of the times before I removed packages.

Comment: Twitter might not have any additional Launcher options when you right click the icon. Try installing the Gmail webapp for instance, I think it has a "compose new email" in the Launcher right click.

Comment: @Alaa Already tried with no luck.

Comment: Is it creating application shortcut in `~/.local/share/applications`? If not create it manually(from `create-application-shortcut` in chromium menu) & drag it to the launcher. [Link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207283/chromium-web-app-creation-doesnt-work-in-12-10).

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I may be wrong, but seems you have Chromium apps in mind, I'm having problem with Unity WebApps.

Comment: True. But you can turn unity-web-apps into chromium-apps. Basically the same website is ruining in standalone mode. See Radu's answer below to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: Have you tried with Firefox (setting it as default browser)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Chromium**, **Desktop Integration** is changed now to **Installed Websites**:

[image: chrome://settings]

---

[image: Installed Websites]

---

[image: Add integrated website]

**Firefox** offers the same functionality through the **General** section:

[image: Firefox Preferences]

Until now you sow where you can find the exceptions for web applications and, implicitly, from where to remove this exceptions. Here is a list of sites that support integration in Ubuntu: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/list-of-that-websites-support-unitys-new-web-apps-feature.

Related to Grooveshark Web App, according with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/203473/147044), is not working for the new layout of the site.

Next you will see how to manually create a simple web application for the sites that doesn't offer integration in Ubuntu.

To add a new web application from **Chromium**, go to **Tools** > **Create Application Shortcut...**:

[image: Create Application Shortcut]

Add the application from desktop to Launcher by dragging and drop:

[image: Application Shortcut]

---

[image: Dash]

The last thing that you can do is to change the icon of application to a better one. To do this, search in **Dash** for `alacarte` to open **Main Menu**:

[image: alacarte]

In **Main Menu** search for the application for which you want to change the icon:

[image: change app icon]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the desktop integration package:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service
```

Reboot or log out and then back in and it should work.

Comment: Nah: "unity-webapps-service is already the newest version."